# Show that the order of any conjugacy class is a power of $p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**Problem:**

> Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Suppose $Aut(N)$ is a $p$-group for a prime $p$. Show that the order of any $G$-conjugacy class in $N$ is a power of $p$.

**My attempt:**
Let $G$ act on $N$ by conjugation, which induces a homomorphism $\varphi:G\to Aut(N)$. By the first isomorphism theorem we then have that $G/\ker(\varphi) \cong im(\varphi) \leq Aut(N)$. Thus I have that $[G:\ker(\varphi)]$ divides $p^k$. However, I'm having trouble relating this back to conjugacy classes. I know $\ker(\varphi)$ is the centralizer of $N$, that is, $C_G(N)$. I also know that $[G:C_G(g_i)]$ is the size of a conjugacy class with representative $g_i$. But I'm still missing something to put this all together.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The orbit of a point has size dividing the order of the group acting, namely $G/\ker(\phi)$. Put another way, $C_G(N)\le C_G(n)$ for all $n\in N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner automorphism group is a $p$-group, being a subgroup of a $p$-group. The conjugacy class has a transitive action by the inner automorphism group. By Burnside's theorem, the conjugacy class has order a power of $p$.